# Difference between trajectory_planner.cpp and trajectory_planner_ros.cpp

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to work with the trajectory planner in `base_local_planner`.

But now I am A bit confused, because the two source files `trajectory_planner.cpp` and `trajectory_planner_ros.cpp` seem to implement the same methods, or at least have a lot of overlap.

Can someone help me on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201479/difference-between-trajectory_planner.cpp-and-trajectory_planner_ros.cpp/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `trajectoy_planner.cpp` implements the basic planning functionality, while `trajectory_planner_ros.cpp` provides the ROS API/communication part (publishers, subscribers etc.). This way of splitting functionality has the advantage that the planning part can be re-used more easily.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-22**:
Does trajectory_planner.cpp update/construct/choose the trajectories? What does the global planner will do then?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2015-01-22**:
Yes, this was also my impression. But I was confused that both seem to implement for example `checkTrajectory`. But the one in `trajectory_planner_ros.cpp` seems to be only a wrapper.